# there is a gap when two line pass the same point, at x=0.3. How to eliminate the gap? Many thanks!

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

[image]

code

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function = {
            func1(\x)= (\x<=0.3) * (10*\x*\x - 3*\x ) + (\x>0.3) * (\x* \x*\x);
            func2(\x)= (\x<=0.3) * (0) + (\x>0.3) * (\x* \x*\x);
        }
    ]
        
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=-0.4,
            ymax=1,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=1,
            ytick={-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1},
            grid
        ]

            \addplot[name path=poly, blue, domain=-0.4:1, smooth]{func1(x)};
            \addplot[name path=poly2, blue, domain=-0.4:1, smooth]{func2(x)};
            \addplot[name path=linear, black, no markers]{x};
            \addplot[name path=line, black, no markers]{0};
            \addplot fill between[
                of = poly and line, split,
                every odd segment/.style={red!10},
                every even segment/.style={yellow!10}
            ];
            \addplot[blue!10] fill between[of = poly2 and linear];
            \node at (axis cs:0.18,-0.05) [anchor=north east] {A};
            \node at (axis cs:0.45,0.2) [anchor=south west] {B};
            \node at (axis cs:0.8,0.3) [anchor=south west] {C};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the hard bend near x=0.3 and the `smooth` option and the then "low" amount of samples where the function is evaluated. You could show that by adding markers to the "func" plots as in the given example below. To circumvent your problem you could simply increase the number of `samples` where the function is evaluated, e.g. to 101. (The default number of `samples` is 25.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=newest,
        width=10cm,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function = {
            func1(\x)= (\x<=0.3) * (10*\x*\x - 3*\x ) + (\x>0.3) * (\x* \x*\x);
            func2(\x)= (\x<=0.3) * (0) + (\x>0.3) * (\x* \x*\x);
        },
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=-0.4,
            ymax=1,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=1,
            ytick={-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1},
            grid,
            domain=-0.4:1,
%            samples=101,   % <-- uncomment me to improve the result
        ]

            \addplot [name path=linear,black] {x};
            \addplot [name path=line,black] {0};
            \addplot [
                name path=poly,
                blue,
                smooth,
                mark=o,
            ] {func1(x)};
            \addplot [
                name path=poly2,
                red,
                smooth,
                mark=+,
            ] {func2(x)};

            \addplot fill between[
                of=poly and line,
                split,
                every odd segment/.style={red!10},
                every even segment/.style={yellow!10}
            ];

            \addplot [blue!10] fill between [of = poly2 and linear];

            \node at (axis cs:0.18,-0.05) [anchor=north east] {A};
            \node at (axis cs:0.45,0.2)   [anchor=south west] {B};
            \node at (axis cs:0.8,0.3)    [anchor=south west] {C};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you so much for your timely reply and wise code. After increasing the sample to 100 or even larger, I noticed there is a kink right after x=0.3, although the two lines of function1 and 2 do become closer to each other. So, your solution solved my question asked here.  I actually do not need function 2, but I want to fill the area marked by B. Do you mind giving me some advice on how to do this?  Sorry for the simple questions.

Comment: You are welcome. The kink is from the `smooth` option. The closer two points get and the harder/steeper a "bend" is between these points the curve tries to keep "smooth". But the more points you have, the less you need the `smooth` option. If that doesn't help you to solve the question, please ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117) since that is a completely other question than the one in the title.

Comment: I C. Great thanks for your patience!

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Thanks! I am quite new here. Not familiar with those buttons. Already done now.

Comment: Not a problem. We help also with this ;)